# Disable ng-table pager buttons while data is loading?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

Is there a way to disable the pagination/pager buttons while data is asynchronously loaded by the data service? I have a temporary solution including jquery which goes like this

```
$(".ng-table-pager button").attr("disabled", true);
```

and then on data loaded i turn it back to false but I find it's a poor solution so I will be thankful if someone would nudge me to the right direction.

Comment: Can't you just use `ng-disabled` on the button, and the expression is anything you want to see if the data is loaded yet?  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create one Boolean variable in your controller, for example -

> var isLoading = false;

Then set it's value true before calling your API (service) and false after finish calling your API from your controller.

Now in your view you have to do something like this:

> div ng-disabled="isloading"> !--your pagination/pager buttons --> /div>

I hope you are clear with the idea.